# SQL joining two tables via large id number

Tags: sql

I have two tables which look like this

```
Value   EntryID
0200    43300008191907010611241000917561326051

Value   EntryID
test    43300008191907010611241000917561326051
```

I want to join them via INNER JOIN over the EntryID number, but even though it is a nvarchar, the join does not work (I get nothing as result, my new table is empty). Why?

```
SELECT * FROM #T_TableA AS A INNER JOIN #T_TableB AS B ON A.EntryID = B.EntryID
```

Comment: Joins on `varchar()` work fine.  This is often due to extra characters (sometimes unseen) at the end of the entryId.  Also, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: First check and display a simple SELECT Query and compare the VALUES of EntryID..........did you try trunc(A.EntryID) AND trunc(B.EntryID) ??? (WHAT DBMS are you using???)

Comment: Trailing spaces shouldn't make any difference (at least if the DBMS is SQL Standard compliant), only leading. If you actually find that TRIMmed values work you should better clean your data and adjust your load process. Or you got other characters which only look like blanks (do you run DB2?)

Comment: This comment assumes SQL Server. ltrim() and rtrim() won't take care of CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) if you have either of those in the `EntryID`s. One thing you could do, is check the length of the values. Are both EntryIDs the same length? As a shot in the dark, you could attempt to use: `replace(replace(EntryID, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''))`

Comment: Just realized I should have also mentioned CHAR(9) as a possible culprit in my above comment as well. `replace(replace(replace(EntryID, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')`

Comment: What values do you get for LEN(EntryID) for both tables?

Comment: @BaconBits LEN() returns 38

Comment: @Acroneos , I could able to join on entry id in oracle. what database you using and what  datatype is entry id. my entry id is nvarchar2(100).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Using varchar, I get the following message when executing query: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe one field contains extra spaces? Use the `TRIM` function to remove spaces:

It should be like:

```
INNER JOIN #T_TableB AS B ON TRIM(A.EntryID) =TRIM(B.EntryID)
```

Or:

```
INNER JOIN #T_TableB AS B ON RTRIM(LTRIM(A.EntryID)) =RTRIM(LTRIM(B.EntryID))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, LTRIM and RTRIM did not help, there are really no whitespaces anywhere, I double-checked.

Comment: Did you just copy my answer? :S

Comment: No look at the time when you post your answer i was writing and checking my answer and i checked if  there is TRIM in mysql at the folowing link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim

Comment: Regarding the link i checked in SQL Server when you link 2 field type varchar the server ignore the spaces .

Comment: Regarding the link i checked in SQL Server when you link 2 field type varchar the server ignore the spaces .I created 2 tables like yours and linked them. in one table i added to the value of entryid 2 spaces and i linked them without using TRIM or LTRIM RTRIM and it work fine and for both of thim it show me that the len is 38 which is the number of digits without spaces

Answer (score -3):

Those cannot be combined using an inner join. Try using a FULL JOIN. If you are trying to yield one single line row try a left or right join. If you are trying to just put the rows in a new table as two rows that look the same use a UNION

Comment: Why can't you inner join? Why would another type of join work?

Comment: inner join combine only rows that match from each table. the "Value" field has different values so inner join will not see these as like rows. however outer (full, left, right) joins will enable you to append the second "value" field. a full join would be sloppy but it would work.